# what is the priority of user defined variable in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, etl

In any SSIS package, we can get the value of a variable in 3 different ways-

1.**From Variable window:** we can set a default value here

2.**From SSIS package configuration:** we can set a value for any variable here

3.**From Batch File:** we can create a batch file, where we can mention a package configuration file in it, executing the batch file will run the package (we can set a different configuration file from the package itself, the variables values are different)

Considering the above scenarios, what will be the priority of the package configuration the package take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of priority will work like this:

1. Use the value supplied by the configuration file
2. Use the default value set at design time

In the first case, this covers both scenarios 2 and 3.  The only difference is in case 3 is that you are replacing the config file.